# Is 10% with accepted answers typical?

Tags: discussion, statistics, accepted-answer

At the current moment posting this, 5 out of the 50 front-page postings
(that I see)
are are accepted answers. My question is:

> ***Q***. Is this typical, about $10$% accepted answers at any one time?

Comment: You have access to  Site analytics, and can take a look.  It doesn't exactly answer your question, but I found that on average about 50 questions are asked a day, and on average about 15-16 acceptances a day.  That suggests a ratio of  30-40%; perhaps more in the end since some questions will be of low quality and would get deleted...

Comment: @Lucia: Thanks. Your estimates are more accurate than my one-snapshot analysis. So I guess all is pretty much normal. There seems to be a very gradual decline in traffic, however measured, on a time scale of months.

Comment: You should edit your title from "answered" to "with accepted answers."